# Is there a word that means "creates a lot of discussion"?

Tags: word-request

I think there was a word or expression that meant that, but the ones I remember aren't nearly similar in meaning, I can't only think of phrase like "has been a hot topic", but it's only vaguely similar and cannot be used in the same context. I am looking for a word, an adjective.

For example:

The new policy enacted by the government is ___.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjective *controversial* might work:

> Giving rise or likely to give rise to controversy or public disagreement.

<sub>(source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/controversial))</sub>

It's derived from the noun *controversy*:

> Prolonged public disagreement or heated discussion.

<sub>(source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/controversy))</sub>